# Multiple Clipping/custom shape Clip

Tags: javascript, css

I have been searching for quite a while but I found nothing, which really helps. 
I want to clip an Image with multiple custom shapes. 
Is it even possible to clip an image multiple times ?
I want for example three hexagons, which aren't connected to each other and in which the 
Image is visible.
Is it possible to clip the image with a custom shape like a hexagon or so ?
I would really appreciate any kind of help !
Thanks

Comment: Where do you get the images? `<img>`? `<canvas>`? Blob? Have you started anything?

Comment: I got the image with <img>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an SVG path as clip-path. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content#Example.3A_Clipping for an example.